# QueryString in xbap wpf application

Tags: wpf, xbap

I have an XBap WPF application runnin on the browser. I  need to pass in a parameter using QueryString. I'm using the following code:

```
if (BrowserInteropHelper.IsBrowserHosted) {
    var query = BrowserInteropHelper.Source.Query;
}
```

IsBrowserHosted property is true, but I get a NullReferenceException because BrowserInteropHelper.Source is always null. Any idea why this happens?